# Passing an array of integers as function parameter in C

Tags: c, arrays, parameters

Please help me, i'm stuck at this.
I have a function which must sum two arrays of integers of size n
and i must pass as arguments for the function the first element of each array
Is this enven close?

```
 12 void sumVect(int * v[], int * w[] ,int n)
 13 //adds the second vector to the first vector; the vectors v and w have exactly n components
 14 {
 15         int i;
 16         for(i=0;i<n;i++)
 17         {
 18                 *v[i]+=*w[i];
 19         }
 20 
 21 }
```

I will give you the whole code

```
#include <stdio.h>

void sumVect(int * v[], int * w[] ,int n)
//adds the second vector to the first vector; the vectors v and w have exactly n components
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        *v[i]+=*w[i];
    }

}


int main()
{   
    int i,j;
    int n = 4;  //the size of a vector
    int k = 5;  //the number of vectors
    int v[k][n];    //the vector of vectors

    printf("How many vectors? k=");
    scanf("%d",&k);

    printf("How many components for each vector? n=");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(i=1;i<=k;i++)   //read the content of each vector from the screen
    {
        printf("\nv%d   |\n_____|\n",i);

        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            printf("v%d[%d]=",i,j);
            scanf("%d", &v[i][j]);
        }
    }

    for(j=1;j<k;j++)
    {
        sumVect(&v[j], &v[j+1], n);
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
            printf("%d",v[j][i]);
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that you are passing type `int []` but your formal parameters in the function is `int *[]` . Therefore your signature should be:

`void sumVect(int v[], int w[] ,int n)`

or

`void sumVect(int *v, int *w,int n)`

Also you should access them in the function like

`v[i] + w[i]` because `v` and `w` both are `int *` or `int []` (depends on the formal paremeter)

Also when calling you should do:

`sumVect(v[j], v[j+1], n);`

or

`sumVect(&v[j], &v[j+1], n);`

This is because as as `v[j]` is type of `int []` ,  `&v[i]` and `v[i]` will evaluate to the same address.

Comment: thanks a lot, the explanations where flawless
i owe you one beer :))

Comment: sorry, i'm not a native english user, what did you mean by downvote cause?

Comment: some one clicked the downvote button, i wanted to know what was the cause for downvoting this answer

Comment: (i'm member of this forum since yesterday so i'm not very familiar with all the features). I don't know if i clicked that button but i'm very sorry if i did it. I find your reply very useful.

Comment: @nickNatra: it is not to you, i am requesting who ever has downvoted to give a cause, so that i can correct.

Answer (score 1):

This is the corrected version of your function sumVect.

```
void sumVect(int * v, int * w ,int n)
//adds the second vector to the first vector; the vectors v and w have exactly n components
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        v[i]+=w[i];
    }

}
```

But whole your needs a number of corrections.
Look at this code:

```
int n = 4;  //the size of a vector
int k = 5;  //the number of vectors
int v[k][n];    //the vector of vectors

printf("How many vectors? k=");
scanf("%d",&k);

printf("How many components for each vector? n=");
scanf("%d",&n);
```

Here is the allocation of 2-dimentional array of size 5x4, and then your program asks the user what the size of the array actually should be.
The simplest way to fix it is to use heap allocation of array. Here is fixed code:

```
int n = 4;  //the size of a vector
int k = 5;  //the number of vectors
int **v = NULL;    //the vector of vectors

printf("How many vectors? k=");
scanf("%d",&k);

printf("How many components for each vector? n=");
scanf("%d",&n);
v = malloc(sizeof(int*), k);
for( int i = 0; i < k; ++i)
   v[i] = malloc(sizeof(int), n);
```

In the end you should free the allocated memory in the similar way, but let it be your homework.

Comment: ok, that was a stupid mistake
i fixed it, thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

Arrays and pointers are generally treated as the same thing in c. An array variable holds the pointer to the array an the [] notation is a shortcut for pointer arithmatic.

Note that n should be an unsigned type.

```
void sumVect(int * v, int * w, uint n)
{
    while (n--)
    {
        *v++ += *w++;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, but n represents how many components each vector has(the statement of the problem says that i must add two arrays having the same number of components ex: v1 = 1 1 1  and v2 = 2 2 2)